# Парсинг txt файла, достав только xml элементы используя c#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, парсер, xml

Есть лог файл, где пишутся xml запрос-ответы и сопроводительная информация:

```
====================962693======================================
2023-11-13T10:50:31
Url: *********
User-Agent: curl/7.55.0
Data:**********
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
</Request>

============================================================

====================962696======================================
2023-11-13T10:50:32
`<Response>...</Response>`
====================962696=======================================
```

Как распарсить файл, достав только xml элементы? т.е. на выходе получить файл
где у меня останется только

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
</Request>
<Response>...</Response>
```

или массив xml объектов

пробовал через регулярное выражение

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(<\?xml version=.*\?>)\n([\s\S]*?)(^.*? End Event \(\d+\) =*?\n)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var match = regex.Match(inputString);
```

Но в match ничего не попадает

Comment: Не нужно здесь регулярное выражение... Проанализируйте синтаксис Вашего лог-файла (а конкретней - с чего начинаются строки) и построчно обрабатывайте файл.

Comment: удалите все строки, которые не начинаются с `<`

Comment: я это сделал ^[A-Z].*|^=.*|^[0-9].*|^$. Как получившиеся строки разбить на конкретные xml объекты?

Comment: Вот так, может, https://regex101.com/r/pkNxr8/1